# How do I fix these misplacements?

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript

My team and I are working in Microsoft's TNT program and we've built a web app that deals with battling misinformation. A component of it deals with rating news articles on various criteria. The problem is I want the stars to align horizontally and the stars to be colored when clicked upon as opposed to the buttons (frankly, I'm not sure why the buttons are even there). Also, for the Objective part, the stars are out of the tile (again not sure how that happened). I'd appreciate anyone helping with making the stars horizontal, getting rid of the buttons and instead it should be the stars getting colored when clicked on, and for the 'Objective' part having the stars within the tile. I've included images, css, and tsx files to help visualize these misplacements. (I'm very new to TypeScript+React so I have limited knowledge on this)

Tsx file:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { FaStar } from "react-icons/fa";
 
const StarRating = () => {
 const [rating, setRating] = useState(0);
 
 return (
 
 <div>
 {[ ... Array(5)].map((star, i) => {
 const ratingValue = i + 1;
 
 return(
 
 <label>
 <input
 type="radio"
 name="rating"
 value={ratingValue}
 onClick={() => setRating(ratingValue)}
 
 />
 <FaStar className="star"
 color={ratingValue <= rating ? "#ffc107" : "#e4e5e9"}
 size={20} />
 </label>
 )
 
 
 })}
 </div>
 );
};
 
export default StarRating;
```

Css file:

```
.StarRating {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 min-height: 100vh;
 flex-direction: row;
 
}
 
input[type = "radio"]{
 display: none;
}
 
.star {
 display: flex;
 cursor: pointer;
 transition: color 200ms;
}
```

Images:
[Stars vertical](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxEiE.png)
[Stars out of tile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/taIKK.png)

Comment: You're not using the `.StarRating` css class ?

Comment: I've edited the code to:

import React, { useState } from "react";
import { FaStar } from "react-icons/fa";
 
const StarRating = () => {
 const [rating, setRating] = useState(0);
 
 return (
 
 <div className="StarRating">
 {[ ... Array(5)].map((star, i) => {
 const ratingValue = i + 1;
...

And still no luck.

Comment: Have you checked the devtools to see if the classes are applied to your DOM? Looks like `input[type = "radio"]` is not taken into account either.

Comment: Maybe you're missing an `import "./my-file.css";` somewhere.

Comment: It's the import that we missed! It's all good now, except the last stars are still out of tile. Thank you so much!